# How can a directory's encryption attribute be toggled from a Powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs

The documentation states that the encryption attribute in a directory is just a flag that indicates that all its children should be encrypted.

For a file, you can toggle encryption with

```
(Get-Item -Path filename).Decrypt()
(Get-Item -Path filename).Encrypt()
```

These methods are defined in `FileInfo` and don't exist in `DirectoryInfo`. In neither case can you set the attribute directly, i.e. this does nothing:

```
(Get-Item -Path filename).Attributes -= 'Encrypted'
```

(This type of attribute setting will work with things like `Archive` and `ReadOnly` but not things like `Compressed`, `Encrypted`, `Directory`, etc.)

What I would like to do is:

1. Create a new directory inside a directory that is encrypted.
2. Set the encrypted attribute to false in this new directory.
3. Fill the new directory with files which will thus not be encrypted.

Is this possible from a script?

Note: I do *not* want to fill the directory first and then go and call `Decrypt()` on every file; this does not solve the problem of having all new files not be encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't obvious (and you have to wonder why `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instances don't expose `.Encrypt()` and `.Decrypt()` methods, as you have to wonder why attempts to remove the `Encrypted` attribute via `.Attributes` are *quietly ignored*), but the [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File) class has static `.Encrypt()` and `.Decrypt()` methods that also operate on *directory* paths.

Therefore:

```bash
# Create a new dir. inside an encrypted dir., which by default
# will have the Encrypted attribute set too.
$dirInfo = New-Item -Type Directory -Path $encryptedDir -Name NewUnencryptedDir

# Remove the Encrypted attribute, so that files and subdirs. created inside
# will be unencrypted.
# Note: Be sure to always pass a *full* path, because .NET's current dir.
#       usually differs from PowerShell's.
[IO.File]::Decrypt($dirInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this question after i was getting failures to disable the encrypt flag of folders after trying all kinds of solutions, including granting Everyone's full control, killing all processes with open handles on the folder etc. and the thumbprint of the certificate was the correct one.

The solution of mkelement0 almost did the trick.

So here is the single line command that managed to unflag the folder in my case:

```
[IO.File]::Decrypt((get-item "<foldername>" -Force))
```